# Why does Nano with error.log open use 40% of RAM?

Tags: apache, logging, ram, nano

Edit: I should clarify 40% of 2GB of RAM

I just happened to catch this on my sever, I had used nano before to open an error log and it was still open I don't know for how long. After killing that task, my ram usage dropped from just over 1GB to 250MB.

I remember coming across this before somewhere, I want to know how to prevent/avoid this in the future. I like nano for its simplicity but yeah, I guess be sure to kill the process or something.

Will have to look into remote status updates or something on the server's "livelihood" haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because `error.log` is a big file (you don't say how big is it). 
Did you try using a pager like `less` on it?

```
less error.log
```

You probably don't want to *edit* (i.e. have the opportunity to *change*) that `error.log` file, you just want to look inside it (with a [terminal pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) like `less`, or `more`, or `most`); a pager uses less memory than an editor, because it does not enable you to change the file.

BTW, consider tuning your [logrotate(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Notice that `nano`, like all editors, need to keep in some complex data structures the content of the edited file, in such ways that modification is efficient. This explains why it takes a lot of memory. Since `nano` is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (and so is [less](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/)), you could study its [source code](https://www.nano-editor.org/git.php) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on less, though I don't know what it is at time time (Google!). It is probably a big file though I thought it automatically zipped it after hitting some threshold?

Comment: The error log is 4.2MB I suppose that is big for just text. Oh I see less is an alternative to nano.

Comment: 5MB is not very big, and is really ok for pagers. And no, `less` (since it is not an *editor* able to *change* file contents) is not an alternative to `nano`, it is the good tool to page thru large text files without changing them.

Comment: Thanks for tip on logrotate I did that in the past, I do have a lot of stupid logs in my error log about failed inserts/notices from PHP from massive batch jobs oh well. Ctrl + V and I see the Matrix.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer per say but I will accept it as it does answer the point about "how to avoid this" by using less instead of nano (to not forget to kill the task despite that it shouldn't persist after exiting nano)